# XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, cross-domain

[image]

XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Refer here, I'm able to solve this and i posted my answer/approach here.[Another Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264021/web-api-cal-from-web-form-ajax-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pre/46212684#46212684)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add duplicated custom header entry, try to define your custom headers like this:

```
<customHeaders>
        <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
```