# Web-API cal from Web Form - AJax. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use web API with Web Forms application to get data through Ajax call.

So created an Web API project and deployed it to local IIS. It respond to the requests.

[image]

And then make an Ajax call in webForm (Default.aspx) to get the data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/Values';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            crossdomain: 'true',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                var r = JSON.stringify(result);
                alert("From Web-API  " + r);
            }
        });
});
```

But this is following error

*"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/Values. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:61605' is therefore not allowed access."*

[image]

Which header am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or just add the proper header in your `web.config` from your web api site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Added this.      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>

Comment: @user2739418, answer edited...i added your header to my answer...cheers

Comment: I have yet to see this stuff actually work,  I just use CORS in webapiconfig.cs

Answer (score 1):

Since your web API and WebForms projects are being hosted on different ports, it's considered a Cross-Domain (CORS) request.  Check out this article which describes how to decorate your Web API controllers to allow CORS access.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: This package is not available for .NET 4.0 (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors). Is there any way to make CORS calls in .NET 4? Also how shall I host on same domain?

Comment: Ah, if you're stuck on .NET 4.0, use Robert Roza's answer for sure!

Comment: Thanks Steve. Unfortunately still many organizations are .NET 4.0 and have no plan to move to .NET 4.5 any sooner :). I guess sometime they don't have infrastructure (windows 2003 server) or sometime fear of Unknown

Answer (score 1):

Most things simply DO NOT fix the problem.

This won't help at all

```
crossdomain: 'true',
```

Do not touch your web.config , get the added in code out of there!

Neither will this, you can end up with issues on multiple response headers if this along with other parts of VERBS are in web.config

```
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

So instead, use Nuget and Add in Asp.net web api  Cors

Then in webapiconfig.cs add in these lines

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Works like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, exactly just like yours. And i did following things in my code base and its started working.

I have installed the following Nuget Package to My Web Api Project. You can install through Package Manager Console or Nuget Package Manager.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

And I added the `New Code` to my `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace SampleWebApi
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is Important part to specify:

Here is my Sample Value Controller API.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace SampleWebApi.Controllers
{
    // You have to Add this One line in your API Controller
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] // Allow CORS for all origins. (Caution!)
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution Tested and it worked well.

Suppose if you know your origin(s), you can specify something like below on top of the Controller class declaration.,

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.contoso.com,http://www.example.com", 
    headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Hope this helps., :)

Comment: And i followed the Tutorial from [Docs.Microsoft.Com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)